# Vlookup kind of formula for text which contains

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a export of a DB which contains multiple entries in a cell.

So e.g.;

A1: "France; Australia; China; Italy"

A2: "Italy"

A3: "China; Russia"

I need to determine if in the cell is ANY country a EU country. So I created a list with:

France    EU

Italy     EU

Australia Non-EU

And via vlookup I try to distinguish if it matches. It works as long as first entry is a EU country, not if 2nd, or 3rd is EU.

Any idea to resolve this? APpreciated!

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53340569/edit), adding the formula you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

**Single-formula solution**

Assuming the DB export column is `A`, and the list of EU countries is in `C1:C6`, the formula in `B1` is:
`=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$1:$C$7;A1)))`
This will give you the number of EU countries in cell `A1`, and you can copy this down next to the entire DB export column. If you want a `TRUE/FALSE` value, just add `>0` at the end of the formula.

The range (`C1:C6` in my example formula) with list of EU countries may not contain any empty cells, but can be in a column or in a row. It is slightly different than the format you put in your question, where you mix both EU and non-EU countries in the same list. But I assume you have the possibilities to sort this column or make a list/range with just the EU countries.

.

[image]

.

**Multiple formulas with helper columns/rows**

Just for completeness, and e.g. if you don't just want to know whether a country belongs to a given country union/association, but you want to look up the association it belongs to, you have two ways of doing this:

1) you can check for each country from your list whether it is present in the DB export, using the `ISNUMBER(SEARCH())` function, which will be `TRUE` if the country is somewhere in the text. (The `SEARCH` function actually gives the position of the search string when found, and the `#VALUE!` error if not . With the `ISNUMBER` function we convert this in `TRUE` or `FALSE`).

2) you can also split the cells that contain multiple countries to extract these individual country names in separate cells, and then you can check with `VLOOKUP` (or `MATCH`) whether these countries are present in the list of countries.

Comment: Peter, tnx for answer. Solution 1 does not work as hoped. Solution 2 does, but splitting is undesireable/practical. Since I have up to 6 countries in the cell.

Comment: What do you mean with "does not work as hoped" ? I would think Solution 2 is more tricky to implement. For Solution 1, it just takes a few helper columns (as many as there are EU countries in your list), which you can hide, or put on a different worksheet, which you also can hide. You check on each country, and then check whether there is one TRUE on the row. It might look cumbersome, but it is very easy and quick to implement.

Comment: Peter, you are right for around 15 columns (# of EU countries) and then the search function. However I was hoping to solve it in one formula.

Comment: @BarryvanderTas I updated my answer with a one-formula solution.

Comment: @BarryvanderTas Did the updated solution work for you ?